# FPDF Image from Dynamic Source. php/png/pdf. Can't get image to work

Tags: php, pdf, png, fpdf

http://babymoments.co/preview/highres%20preview/5_357/

According to the FPDF documentation here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm
You are supposed to be able to use an Image from a dynamic source.. however, as per the first link, i'm getting an fopen error.

Any suggestions?

Code Snippet:

```
// Overlay Text & Images
$pdf->Image($conf['rbase'].'page_maker/image_hr.php?id=5&side=1&bg=cover_pink&lo=0_1&imgtxt=0|0|u5_1310329746.jpg@@1|1|Elina\'s Puppies 9/2/2010|15|arial_bi.ttf|db0ddb|fedfe4&applet_type=cover',$sx,$sh,(0-$dpi), 0, 'png');
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth to share the actual error message you're getting if you're looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to open a local php file with get parameters - try instead to open the image file as a url. For example :

```
http://domain.com/image.php?id=5
```

Or in your case...

```
http://babymoments.co/preview/page_maker/image_hr.php?id=5&side=1&bg=cover_pink&lo=0_1&imgtxt=0|0|u5_1310329746.jpg@@1|1|Elina's%20Puppies%209/2/2010|15|arial_bi.ttf|db0ddb|fedfe4&applet_type=cover
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't fetch the preview over HTTP but would include the required code and generate the image in the same script that generates the PDF. That way there is no problems with setups that have disabled fopen()-usage with URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I was implementing a barcode for a label printer. So I was using the 'barcodegen' library and 'fpdf' library for this project, but I was having problems including dynamically the image generated with barcodegen, giving me the following error:

FPDF error: Not a PNG file: ./misc/barcodegen/mostrar-codigo-bcgcode39.php

Afeter that, I use one of the answers described here, and I solved the problem using the full URL of the image, like this:

$pdf->Image("http://localhost/caaf/misc/barcodegen/mostrar-codigo-bcgcode39.php",0,0,20,0,'PNG');

And it worked for me.